# What Does NASM GOT Documention Mean Here?

Tags: debian, nasm, relocation

I am reading this section here specifically starting on the 9.2 section: https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.14.02/html/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.4

I've been reading this all day and I want to make sure I understand what is going on here before proceeding. I believe they are saying we need to enforce position independent code because when using a shared library, the relocation when accessing some global must not be hardcoded. So to do so we use the global offset table.

Still I believe they proceed to say:

```
        call    .get_GOT 
.get_GOT: 
        pop     ebx 
        add     ebx,_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+$$-.get_GOT wrt ..gotpc
```

achieves using the GOT by first pushing the value ebx onto the stack, where .get_GOT places the location of the GOT relative to the rip register and returns it in ebx.

That is all I believe I understood correctly. If anybody could clarify what happens in this

```
add     ebx,_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+$$-.get_GOT wrt ..gotpc
```

I would greatly appreciate it. Also please break it up into sections regarding the whole 2nd operand portion in that add instruction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those crazy things that is somehow still a thing... and very poorly explained everywhere I have seen it.

I will answer using 64-bit registers, because the world is 64-bit these days, and pointers are 64-bits.

After the call and push, `rbx` contains the address of `.get_GOT`.  This is because the call pushes `rip` onto the stack, and `rip` always points to the address following the current instruction (usually the *next* instruction).  Thus the pop moves the absolute address of `.get_GOT` into `rbx`.  So far, so good.

`_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_` is a symbol (it's in the symbol table for the ELF file) that is defined to point to the start of the GOT.  Why not just use `mov rbx, _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_`?  For reasons that are lost to history... or at least lost to me.  This instruction works fine on my (64-bit) machine.  Likewise, `$$` is a symbol defined to point to the start of the current section.

Source: [NASM Manual § 10.2.1](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo10.html#section-10.2.1)

Now, let's do some address math.

```
    add ebx,   _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ + $$ - .get_GOT wrt ..gotpc
=   .get_GOT + _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ + $$ - .get_GOT wrt ..gotpc
```

Note that we have `.get_GOT - .get_GOT`.  We can get rid of that.

```
=   .get_GOT + _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ + $$ - .get_GOT wrt ..gotpc
=   _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ + $$ wrt ..gotpc
```

Now, let's look at the definition for `wrt ..gotpc`.

> Referring to the symbol marking the global offset table base using wrt ..gotpc will end up giving the distance from the beginning of the current section to the global offset table. (((*GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE*)) is the standard symbol name used to refer to the GOT.) So you would then need to add $$ to the result to get the real address of the GOT.
>
> source: [NASM Manual § 8.9.3](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.9.3)

Based on this, we can replace the expression `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ wrt ..gotpc` with the expression `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ - $$`.  (This is likely positive, because the GOT will most likely be in a higher address than the program.)  This explains the need to add `$$` as mentioned in the NASM manual.

We substitute.

```
=   _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ + $$ wrt ..gotpc
=   $$ + _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ wrt ..gotpc
=   $$ + (_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ - $$)
=   _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
```

Et voilà!  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I have some troubles on understand all the context.

CALL *x* is an equivalent to PUSH RIP, JMP *x*

So next instruction you get the current RIP.

Note: this code is feed to linker, so linker will read the code and put the correct CALL address, but NASM cannot know such address at assembly time.

The last instruction is an ADD: we add EBX to a constant. Yes, a constant will be calculates at assembly time.

We lack enough information to go in details, but as you see, we add from RIP (in ebx) an offset.

> *$$ evaluates to the beginning of the current section;* [section 3.5](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.14.02/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5)

For the wrt operator: [section 7.6](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.6), and pprobably this section will explain much better the code you are looking.

I have too much rust on NASM to go further.